# [A]How to make a MP3 repeat in javafx?

Tags: javafx

i want my mp3 file repeat again after it finished . but i'm unable to create a loop to play my file repeatedly
(i used this code but only it plays first second of my file after it finished)

```
AudioClip myMusic ....   
myMusic.setCycleCount(AudioClip.INDEFINITE);
myMusic.play();
```

Edited :
i used MediaPlayer but it's cycle counter didn't work correctly for example first time i played my mp3 file it played 2 times and in 3rd time of playing suddenly it stops
second time i ran again my app and it played 1 time and in half of second time of playing it stops
here is my code :

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("abcd.mp3");
     MediaPlayer a =new MediaPlayer(new Media(resource.toString()));
     a.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

 a.play();
```

any ideas?thanks in advance .

Comment: What is `myMusic.bgSound`? It is not a field of `AudioClip`, assuming `myMusic` is an `AudioClip`.

Comment: edited : myMusic is an AudioClip

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer to this question, not in the question itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i found my solution i used setOnEndOfMedia method :

```
 URL resource = getClass().getResource("abcd.mp3");
 MediaPlayer a =new MediaPlayer(new Media(resource.toString()));
 a.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         a.seek(Duration.ZERO);
       }
   });
  a.play();
```

Comment: Make sure to mark this question as the answer (little green check mark) as soon as you can.

Comment: But why the original solution isn't working? I have the same problem. When I use `setCycleCount(AudioClip.INDEFINITE);` My wav file repeats about 5 times then stops. [UPDATE] Eevn your solution does not work for me

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Wanted to give you the solution to this problem if you're still in need. If you're going to use MediaPlayer to play your sound it needs to be placed inside a MediaView attached to the current scene. That's why it stops playing. Sometimes if focus is lost on whatever your window is it will stop playing. If you put MediaPlayer in MediaView and put it in your pane it should not stop playing.

Comment: @PhilipVaughn Thanks. I'm gonna check it but it seems very illogical if it needs to be placed inside a MediaView

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator kinda thought that myself when I first started using them but I kept wondering why the dumb thing kept stopping. Once I placed it in a MediaView that was in my root Stackpane the problem went away. Take a look at the following "bug" and look at the final response https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138754

Comment: @PhilipVaughn It seems we could also declare it as an instance variable instead so GC leaves it alone. From your link : "Changing sound to a field fixed the problem"

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator yes however if you dispose of that page for whatever reason it will also stop. My instance was a game I was building and I put the MediaView in the root Stackpane and it was fine (because I was constantly switching screens and an instance variable may have been lost for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

for avoiding the suddenly stopping, you must :

```
a.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            a.play();
        }
    });
```

It works for me.