# Javafx AudioClip not looping

Tags: java, loops, javafx, playback

Now, I assume that this can be due to any number of issues in my gui's code, but, I want to ask, is there anything blatantly wrong with the following code?

```
public class music 
{
    static AudioClip currentMusic;

    public static void playMusic()
    {
        currentMusic = new AudioClip(Paths.get("src/test.mp3").toUri().toString());
        currentMusic.setCycleCount(INDEFINITE);
        currentMusic.play();
    }
}
```

The AudioClip loads properly, plays properly, but no matter what the `setCycleCount` value is, it always stops after playing once.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the caller `playMusic();` before `musicPlaying = false`.

```
musicPlaying = false;
playMusic();
```

Comment: Nothing happened. In fact, forget about the `stopMusic();` function. I removed it from the question, as it doesn't change the outcome one bit.

Comment: Try setting setCycleCount(/* Number of length of the file*/)

Comment: Try writing `if(currentMusic.isPlaying()){ playMusic(); } else{ currentMusic.play(); }`

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc for `AudioClip` if you have `setCycleCount(INDEFINITE)` then it will continue to loop until `stop()` is called. Assuming this, I would check through the rest of your code to ensure you don't have a `stop()` call somewhere.

Comment: That's the weird thing, I've got nothing in my code that could possibly interact with this...
I know it sounds vague. If I get nothing out of it, I'll try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've just tested this, simply using hello world and making the button start the `AudioClip` and have got the same result. Only plays once - tested using `setCycleCount(2)` and `setCycleCount(INDEFINITE)`.

Comment: I also added a `while` loop after it starts, checking the `isPlaying()` return value to see if it thought it was still playing, but it does change to `false` after one play.

Comment: Apparently there's some bug in JavaFX 8, then? I guess one could use a loop to keep restarting it as soon as it stops, but that's crude and probably resource-intensive. I'll try to work with a generic `Media` class, though it seems to have a lot of drawbacks against `AudioClip`.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me, at least from how I interpret the doc, but I haven't used `AudioClip` enough to know for sure. Yes, I did see a solution to a [similar problem here with a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498376/ahow-to-make-a-mp3-repeat-in-javafx)

Comment: Well, the `Media` class works. Thanks for your help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as the problem is common to ReadyPlayer2, it seems that this is some sort of bug. A loop like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498376/ahow-to-make-a-mp3-repeat-in-javafx) could probably work, and the `Media` class certainly works, albeit with certain drawbacks to the `AudioClip`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the last answer but I think I found the solution. Apparently looping doesn't work for .mp3 files, converting the file into .wav solved the issue for me!