# JavaFX2 play wav in background

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

So I'm trying to play indefinitly a song on a background thread, but when the music ends it does not loop as it was supose to.

Tried the offered solution but yet no joy! Here is the code for the main class, hope this helps in the resolution of the issue.

Even tried to loop the thread, but no joy...

Not sure why it's ending after playing the full file once, but not sure how to solve it!

Here is the code I have. Any help is welcome

```
      public class Main extends Application {
  Media sugar = new Media(this.getClass().getResource("sounds/t1coSugar.wav").toExternalForm());

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Main.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    primaryStage.setTitle("pacman");
    primaryStage.setWidth(MazeData.calcGridX(MazeData.GRID_SIZE_X + 2)); //stage size x
    primaryStage.setHeight(MazeData.calcGridY(MazeData.GRID_SIZE_Y + 5)); //stage size y

//splash screen

//end of splash screen

    final Group root = new Group();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    root.getChildren().add(new Maze());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    int playbackgroundmusic = playbackgroundmusic(); 

  }

  private int playbackgroundmusic() 
{
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
            public void run() {
                playSugar(); //method of the music
            }
        };
        // Run the task in a background thread
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
        // Terminate the running thread if the application exits
        backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
        // Start the thread
        backgroundThread.start();                
                return 0;
    }


public void playSugar()
{
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(sugar);    
        mediaplayer.volumeProperty().setValue(0.4);
        mediaplayer.setStartTime(Duration.seconds(0));
        mediaplayer.setStopTime(Duration.seconds(67));
        mediaplayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaplayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
        mediaplayer.play();

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498376

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[A\]How to make a MP3 repeat in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498376/ahow-to-make-a-mp3-repeat-in-javafx)

Comment: Not working, tried before posting :(